# How to activate "active" class to selected menu item in header.php file

Tags: php, css

I have few menu items in header.php file.

and calling "header.php" file in few pages like About us, Contact Us....

How can i highlight the selected menu item using php?

```
<ul>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $CFG->wwwroot;?>"><?php echo get_string('home'); ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://yourdomain.com/course/index.php"><?php echo get_string('courses'); ?></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://yourdomain.com/aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://yourdomain.com/blog/index.php">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://yourdomain.com/gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://yourdomain.com/contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li></ul>
```

This is my header.php

Comment: Check which script it is and set some different CSS styles.

Comment: CSS is not applying to the selected menu items

Answer (score 1):

Get the page URL from the URL as below -

```
<?php 
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; 
//get components of url
$parts = parse_url($url);
//echo $parts['path'];
?>
```

and then add the condition to your HTML element as

```
<li <?php if($parts['path']=="/course/index.php") { echo "class='active'";} ?>><a href="http://yourdomain.com/course/index.php"><?php echo get_string('courses'); ?></a></li>
<li <?php if($parts['path']=="/about.php") { echo "class='active'";} ?>><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
<li <?php if($parts['path']=="/contact.php") { echo "class='active'";} ?>><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
```

Change the page name and URL accordingly

Comment: It's not working for me with my code. I have <ul> tag in <div>

Comment: This is working with aboutus.php, contactus.php and gallery.php.

Comment: blog page redirects from domainname/blog/index.php and courses page redirects from courses/index.php

Comment: @RajKumarJillella i have updated the code. This should work with all URLs you have.

Comment: i used the updated code. the selected menu not highlighting, and when i go to aboutus.php from course page, the domain getting "http://yourdomain/course/about.php" with 404 file not found.

Comment: i have already mentioned there to change the URL. You need to change the href part to match your directory structure. For example : change <a href="about.php"> to <a href="http://yourdomain.com/about.php">

Comment: CSS is not effecting to this. <style>ul li .active {background-color: orange;}</style>

Comment: The css is not applying to selected menu.

Comment: Remove the space between li and .active. This should be ul li.active {background-color: orange;}